# Negating a condition

Tags: bash

I want to negate a condition

Does one usually do

```
! [[ predicate == "VERIFIED" ]]
```

or

```
[[ ! predicate == "VERIFIED" ]]
```

Comment: `[[ $predicate != VERIFIED ]]`

Comment: `[[ $predicate == "VERIFIED" ]] || { echo "Not verified"; }` can also work, depending on what you'll do with the result of the comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to affirmatively test for inequality, why not do so?

```
[[ predicate != "VERIFIED" ]]
```